# Styling jQuery Scale Effect

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

I have a quick question regarding the scale effect...

I have a crude animation I am trying to accomplish.  I have a quick fadeIn and then list elements scaling and fading out on the screen:

```
   jQuery("#page_content").fadeOut(2000, function() {
    jQuery("#intro_animation").slideDown(2500, function () {
      var delay_duration = 10;  

      jQuery("ul#intro_words > li").each(function(index) {
        jQuery(this).delay(delay_duration).hide("scale", {percent: 700, origin: 'center', fade: 'hide' }, 2000);
        delay_duration += 2000;
      });

      jQuery("#intro_animation").delay(delay_duration).slideUp(2500, function() {
        jQuery("#page_content").fadeIn(2000);
      });
    });
  });
```

My problem is in styling the affected text elements that they get cutoff on the right hand side.  Does anyone know of a solution that would prevent the text from getting cut off?

Comment: Post a link to the example so we can see your markup too

Comment: Think I figured it out... not sure if you know of a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out it... it's not 100% centered (more like 99%) but seems to work without getting the text cut off.

```
ul#intro_words > .ui-effects-wrapper > li {
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-indent: -20px;
}
```

Comment: If you remove the padding. it will be centered

Comment: It's not that it wasn't centered - it was.  As the text scales the right side gets cut off.